# Create a loop of templates (ng-include) from a JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this JSON with list of topics and path to the template (ng-include) of this topic, like this:

> {"id":"01","title":"Primeiros Passos no sistema",
>   "url":"static/doc/01.html" },

I already can make a list from the JSON with NG-REPEAT, but how can I make a list of my templates in javascript?

```js
angular.module('duall')
.controller('documentationController', [
 '$scope', 
 '$http', 
  function($scope, $http){

 $scope.docs = [];

 
 $http.get('static/titles.json').success(function(doc){
  $scope.docs = doc;
 }).error(function(error){
  console.log(error);
 });

 //caminho onde estão os arquivos
 //var path = "static/doc/";
 //caminho para os templates 'htmls' de cada parte da documentação já formatados
 //$scope.templates = [
 //{name: 'Primeiros Passos', url:path+'01.html'},
 //{name: 'Login', url:path+'02.html'}
 //];

 for(i = 0; i < $scope.docs.$index; i++ ){
  $scope.templates.name[i] = $scope.docs.name[i];
  $scope.templates.url[i] = $scope.docs.url[i];
 }

 $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];


 $scope.cliked = function(index){
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[index];
  console.log(index);
 };

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="documentationController">
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col s3" >
    
    
    <div class="input-field col s12" >      
      <input id="search" type="search" ng-model="q" aria-label="filter docs"/>
      <label for="search"><strong>Pesquise Algo! :)</strong></label>
      <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
    </div>
    
    
    <ul class="animate-container">
      <!-- <li ng-repeat="docs in docs | orderBy:'title' | filter:q as results "> -->
      <li  ng-repeat="docs in docs | filter:q as results ">
        <i class="material-icons tiny">search</i>
        <a ng-click="cliked($index)" href="">{{docs.title}}</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <br>
      </li>

      <li ng-if="results.length === 0">
        <strong>Nada encontrado :(</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>  
    
        
  </div> <!-- Fim col s3 -->


  <div id="container-doc" class="col s9">
  <br>
  <div class="container left" ng-include="template.url">
      
  </div>
  </div>

  </div><!-- Fim col s9 -->


</div><!-- fim ROW -->
</div><!-- Fim Controller -->
```

Comment: are you asking how you would use javascript to define your templates?  (ex. where to define the html for static/doc/01.html)

Comment: Nop, how can i use Javascript to define all the templates with a loop, the "path" to the templates will be on a json.

Comment: Would [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)  do what you need?  `$templateCache.put('static/doc/01.html', '<div>The html for Doc 01</div>');`  and just put that in a loop in the controller or service or wherever you are loading the json

Comment: not realy, let me explain, i have this JSON with the "url" from the template file in the server, like 
"C:/templates/01.html", i want to make a loop in this JSON file to create a template array.